# How do I close Database Connection Datastax Java Driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, datastax

I am using Datastax Java Driver.
There is a tutorial to use the same.

What I do not understand is how would one close the connection to cassandra?
There is no close method available and I assume we do not want to shutdown the Session as it it expected to be one per application.

Regards
Gaurav

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr Calling `shutdown` on `Session` is the correct way to close connections.

You should be safe to keep a `Session` object at hand and shut it when you're finished with Cassandra - this can be long-lived. You can get individual connections in the form of `Session` objects as you need them and shut them down when done but ideally you should only create one Session object per application. A Session is a fairly heavyweight object that keeps pools of pools of connections to the node in the cluster, so creating multiple of those will be inefficient (and unnecessary) ([taken verbatim from advice given by Sylvain Lebresne on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/java-driver-user/-ifo7gSSeQM)). If you forget to shut down the session(s) they will be all closed when you call `shutdown` on your `Cluster` instance... really simple example below:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(host).withPort(port).build();
Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

// Do something with session... 

session.shutdown();
cluster.shutdown();
```

Comment: There isn't any `shutdown` method in session and cluster classes.You must use `close` method of their classes.`session.close();
        cluster.close();`

Comment: This has changed http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/python/3.2/_modules/cassandra/cluster.html#Session.shutdown && 
http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/python/3.2/_modules/cassandra/cluster.html#Cluster.shutdown

Answer (score 1):

See here - [http://www.datastax.com/drivers....](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/apidocs/com/datastax/driver/core/PoolingOptions.html)

> The driver uses connections in an asynchronous manner. Meaning that
>   multiple requests can be submitted on the same connection at the same
>   time. This means that the driver only needs to maintain a relatively
>   small number of connections to each Cassandra host. These options
>   allow the driver to control how many connections are kept exactly.
>
> For each host, the driver keeps a core pool of connections open at all
>   times determined by calling . If the use of those connections reaches
>   a configurable threshold , more connections are created up to the
>   configurable maximum number of connections. When the pool exceeds the
>   maximum number of connections, connections in excess are reclaimed if
>   the use of opened connections drops below the configured threshold
>
> Each of these parameters can be separately set for LOCAL and REMOTE
>   hosts (HostDistance). For IGNORED hosts, the default for all those
>   settings is 0 and cannot be changed.